# How to run a Cenos7 docker image on an ARM based Mac

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, dockerfile, arm

I am tring to create a `Dockerfile` to run CentOS. One of the host systems needing to run this container is an ARM based (m1) Mac. These are the two files I have created so far.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM centos:7
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"

services:
  genesis:
    build: .
```

When trying to run/build this cointainer I get the following error

```
Building genesis
[+] Building 0.9s (4/4) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 77B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:7                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
 => [auth] library/centos:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:7:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch oauth token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fcentos%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": read tcp 192.168.1.209:64469->3.228.155.36:443: read: software caused connection abort
ERROR: Service 'genesis' failed to build : Build failed
```

After some google searching and answers on stack overflow it looks like the issue is something to do with the architecture difference between the containers and the host. I have tried setting the dockerfile to

```
FROM --platform=aarch/arm centos:7
```

and

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 centos:7
```

but neither of these work, and they're returning the same error as before. I have also tried specifying the `platform` in the docker-compose file too but that didn't work either.

Interestingly I did seem to have it working when I use the command in the shell

```
$ docker run --rm -it --platform=linux/amd64 centos:7 sh
```

but I need to have it working in the dockerfile as I need to then have more setup in the dockefile

Answer (score 2):

Ran into your question searching for something else, but you might try the following (this was probably not available when you wrote your question):

In docker for Mac, go to Settings --> Features in development, and enable 'Use Rosetta ...' setting.

[image]

This worked for me when setting up dev-containers (another use-case where I needed Linux images)

Answer (score 0):

Docker isn't a virtual machine, so there are some limitations.

Your application is for Linux, but you appear to be trying to run it from macOS?

Does your FROM lines specify a version of Linux?

If so, you need a build a new container of binaries native to macOS and avoid using Linux containers in your FROM lines.